# Combine 3 files into one

Tags: linux, sorting, grep, cat

I have 3 files.

**File1**

```
Red
Blue
Green
```

**File2**

```
Apple LadyBug Fire Red Set1
Lettuce Grass Frog Green Set1
Jean Ocean Sky Blue Set1
```

**File3**

```
BlueBerries Blue Set2
Rose Red Set2
Tree Green Set2
```

**Output**

```
Red
Apple LadyBug Fire Red Set1
Rose Red Set2
```

---

```
Blue
Jean Ocean Sky Blue Set1
BlueBerries Blue Set2
```

.
.
.

```
Cat File1 File2 File3 > output4 | sort -u
```

Or

```
Grep -f File1 Filew File3 > output4
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: cat File1 File2 File3 | sort -u >  output4

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what is the logic of combining the files?

Answer (score 1):

I think your are trying to use the `file1` like the pattern. 
Then this should work:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    echo -e "\n-------"; 
    for foo in 'file2 file3'; do 
          echo $line; 
          grep -h $line $foo; 
    done; 
done < file1
```

Comment: You can condense quite a bit. `for line in $(cat File1); do grep -hF $line File[123]; done` ... could add the horizontal rule line in that single loop too.

Comment: sure, however [Why you don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)